# Saving images in SQLite file - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

How can i save a bunch of images (`png`) into a `SQLite` database file, and distribute it in applications.

I know that we are capable of storing some text data in a `SQLite` database file and distribute it in the application. But, how can one save images ?

Comment: How large do you expect the images to be? Usually it is more appropriate to store the images in the local file system and use the database to store liks to them. Also: consider using CoreData instead of raw sql

Answer (score 1):

You can save it as a BLOB (binary long object) type. This means that it will save the image as binary data inside the table just like you would save regular text.

I think you can create an UIImage object using only it's data, try "initImageWithData" method or something similar in the UIImage framework.

Comment: Is there any tutorial, so i could understand this better

Answer (score 0):

You could save binaries as well.
Use BLOB.
Just replace String/Text with byte[]/Blob

http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

A general tutorial for SQLite with android is available here
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

For iPhone this may be helpful
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: Is there any tutorial to try this out ?